# Why is ' not in' working when in a case command?

Tags: sql, db2

So i have this query where i am trying to get the elements are not in the first States but the first case it's not doing anything to filter it.

```
 (case
when upper(STATE) not in()
then
(case
when upper(STATE) in() and DEPT in ('')
 or ()=''
AND upper() in())
then 'SOPORTE'
when upper(STATE) in()
and DEPT in () or ((DEPT)=''
AND upper(USER) in())
then 'PENDIENTE'
else 'OTROS'
end  
)

else (case

end) as ejemp,
```

Truth be told i dont see anything wrong with the query.

Comment: It's hard to tell what exactly you're trying to achieve with your query. Please add some sample data and explain logic you're trying to implement in more detail

Answer (score 0):

You should note what platform and version of Db2.  But I believe the following applies to all platforms...

`IN` is a

> predicate compares a value or values with a set of values.

`upper(STATE) not in()` makes no sense.

`upper(STATE) NOT IN ('OH','UT')` would make sense.

as would `upper(STATE) NOT IN (select state from someothertable)`

Are you by chance looking for `NOT NULL`?